# How to map inside of the map component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

There is a return statement that map inside of array and return some data. What if in category there is another array and for correct data it should be another map in *category={item.category}*. What the best solution to organize this? Thanks.

```
  <div className="portfolio__container">
      {projects.map((item, key) =>
        item.filtered === true ? (
          <div>
            <ProfileCard
              key={key}
              name={item.name}
              title={item.title}
              image={item.image}
              className="border-box"
              exerpt={item.exerpt}
              git={item.git}
              url={item.url}
              category={item.category}
              click="Push"
              sans-serif
              mb0-l
              mb3
              flex-none
              w5
              mr3
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )
      )}
    </div>
```

data

```
{
  name: `object`,
  title: `3 title`,
  image: `photo-2.jpg`,
  exerpt: `some 3 project`,
  git: `https://github.com/desmukh/gatsby-starter-woo/tree/master/`,
  url: `https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll/`,
  category: ["all23423423", "mobile", "ux-ui", "others"],
},
```

Component style

```
export const ProfileCard = ({
  name,
  title,
  click,
  exerpt,
  image,
  git,
  url,
  category,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Card {...props}>
    <Box tc>
      <Avatar src={image} title={`Photo of ${name}`} dib />
      <Button href={git}> {click}</Button>
      <Button href={url}> {click}</Button>
      <Heading level={2} f3 mb2>
        {name}
      </Heading>
      <Text f5 fw4 gray mt0>
        {exerpt}
      </Text>
      <Text>{category}</Text>
    </Box>
  </Card>
);
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the language and framework to ensure it is seen by the users most likely to be able to answer it.

Comment: @Nick tnx, thought since it's JavaScript any solution will be nice.

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't tag the question with `javascript` it won't get seen by as many people as some users only watch their preferred tags.

Comment: @Nick, yes, correct. Appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code for ProfileCard

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier i added, but it's just a Styled Component, magic with mapping is where the data is declaring.

Comment: right now since category is a string your code is working. if you want to change category into an array you need to map through it and render it inside the profile card component. do this inside the profile card component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a possible solution. This will render correctly if category is string or array.

```
    export const ProfileCard = ({
  name,
  title,
  click,
  exerpt,
  image,
  git,
  url,
  category,
  ...props
}) => {
 const renderCategory = () => {
   if(Array.isArray(category)){
     return (<>{
         category.map(cat => <Text>{cat}</Text>);
     }</>);
   } 
    return <Text>{category}</Text>;
 }

 return (<Card {...props}>
    <Box tc>
      <Avatar src={image} title={`Photo of ${name}`} dib />
      <Button href={git}> {click}</Button>
      <Button href={url}> {click}</Button>
      <Heading level={2} f3 mb2>
        {name}
      </Heading>
      <Text f5 fw4 gray mt0>
        {exerpt}
      </Text>
      {renderCategory()}
    </Box>
  </Card>)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a nice way!